# The qnum doesn't show on the Word document

Tags: asp.net

I need to print a test with 3 parts to a Word document. Part 1-question 1 to question 56. Part2-question 57 to question 66; Part3-question 67-question 100. Part 1 and Part 2 questions are required to be on two columns on paper. For example, questions appear on the first page are following.

```
1.          7. 
2.          8.
3.          9.
4.          10. 
5.          11.
6.          12.
```

I have created code behind and the report PT.rdlc. All questions are showed up nicely on the Word doc except some of the question numbers are dropped off. I can't figure out why. Here are some my codes:

```
int TRow = Dt.Rows.Count;  //TRow = number of rows in Part1 or Part2
for (int RowCount = 0; RowCount < TRow; RowCount++)
{
  TDt.Rows.Add(1);
  if (RowCount < TRow)
    TDt.Rows[TDt.Rows.Count - 1]["ID"] = Dt.Rows[RowCount]["qnum"]; //q1
  if RowCount + 6 < TRow
    TDt.Rows[TDt.Rows.Count - 1]["TID"] = Dt.Rows[RowCount + 6]["qnum"]; //q7
  ....
}
```

I do the same way above for all questions in Part 1 and 2. In the report, I use expressions as following for question numbers.

```
=iif(Fields!question.Value<>"",Fields!ID.Value & ". ","") and
=iif(Fields!Tquestion.Value<>"",Fields!TID.Value & ". ","")
```

Can you please help me to identify what is wrong with some question numbers are dropped off? Thank you in advance.